# Can not run Serentiy Cucumber Test using tags from command line

Tags: maven, command-line-interface, cucumber-serenity, serenity

---

I can run Serentiy Test using mvn clean verify command which uses the tags mentioned in cucumber test runner file.
I want to run the test from command line using specified tags. i.e. mvn verify -Dcucumber.options = "--tags=@UI"
Throws error - Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --tags=@UI

POM file :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>XX.XX.XXX</groupId>
<artifactId>ABC_DEMO</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>TASK</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <serenity.version>4.0.29</serenity.version>
    <serenity.maven.version>4.0.18</serenity.maven.version>
    <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
    <rest.assured.version>5.3.2</rest.assured.version>
    <json.version>20231013</json.version>
    <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.1.2</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
    <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>3.1.2</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>2.6.0</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.plugin.version>
    <parallel.tests>4</parallel.tests>
    <tags></tags>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${rest.assured.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>${json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Run parallel tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <forkCount>${parallel.tests}</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <includes>**/TestRunner*.java</includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I did try to change various version of surefire and failsafe version,
but still no luck.
I did try -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@UI" but still no luck, it did not throw specific error but state build failure.

Expectaton:
Tags should be parsed and run selected test ?

Comment: My Cucumber Test Runner file :

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = "xx.xx.xx.stepDefinitions",
        plugin = "pretty",
        tags = "@Regression"
)

public class TestRunner {
}